# Can't browse to big files and upload in browsers (chrome, firefox and explorer under wine)

Tags: wine, firefox, google-chrome, upload, jpeg

I can't upload jpegs over 3mb to photo websites (society6 and blue canvas) because they do not show in the browse files box. Smaller jpegs show up and can be uploaded (900kb or so). What could be causing this strange behaviour?